# Regex for price doesn't work

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex which matches any number followed by a string which consists of digits, spaces, dots and commas followed by "Kč" or "Eur".

The problem is that my `regex` sometimes doesn't find all such strings.

```
((\d[., \d]+)(Kč|Eur))
```

For example:

```
re.findall("""((\d[., \d]+)(Kč|Eur))""","Letenky od 12 932 Kč",flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

returns nothing instead of `[(12 932 Kč,12 932,Kč)]`

Do you know what is wrong with the regex?

Comment: That letter seems different, try [`\d[., \d]*\s*(?:K(?:č|č)|Eur)`](https://regex101.com/r/3Rv3M2/1). See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/g1sO47).

Comment: Strings are from HTML and  there were sometimes \xa0 instead of regular space so I normalized all strings: unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input string contains a multibyte letter consisting of a base `c` letter and a diacritic, and the regex contains the precompose letter with Unicode code point `\u010D`.

You may use

```
(\d(?:[., \d]*\d)?)\s*(K(?:c\u030C|\u010D)|Eur)
```

Or

```
(\d[., \d]*)\s*(K(?:č|č)|Eur))
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/3Rv3M2/1) ([second regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Rv3M2/3)) and [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gztzYv).

**Pattern details**

- `\d` - a digit
- `(?:[., \d]*\d)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `[., \d]*` - zero or more digits, spaces, `.` or `,`
  - `\d` - a digit
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(?:K(?:c\u030C|\u010D)|Eur)` - either `K` followed with either `c\u030C` or `\u010D`, or `Eur` values.

When defining the currency regex, use `CZK = ['Czk','K(?:č|č)']` or `CZK = ['Czk', r'K(?:c\u030C|\u010D)']`.

Comment: Thanks, your regex works but there are two problems. 1. It returns only one group [(12 932 Kč)] and the second, bigger problem is that in fact, I use multiple currencies from variables so I can't process characters like "č" separately. I have a list for every currency. EUR = ['Eur','€']; CZK = ['Czk','Kč'] and in regex: "((\d[., \d]+)({}))".format('|'.join(CZK+EUR)

Comment: Ok, keep the capturing groups then, but as for the list of currencies, you should use `CZK = ['Czk','K(?:č|č)']`

Answer (score 3):

As Wiktor Stribiżew commented, the `Kč` in your regexp is different from the `Kč` in your text. You can use the [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) module to normalize both:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("""((\d[., \d]+)(Kč|Eur))""", "Letenky od 12 932 Kč", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
[]
>>> import unicodedata
>>> re.findall(unicodedata.normalize("NFD", """((\d[., \d]+)(Kč|Eur))"""), unicodedata.normalize("NFD", "Letenky od 12 932 Kč"), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
[('12 932 Kč', '12 932 ', 'Kč')]
```